# How to judge the steam is a jpeg stream?

Tags: libjpeg

I use the libjpeg to decode a stream, But I must to know it is a jpeg stream first, Do you know the way to judge the stream is or not a jpeg stream?
or how to judge a file is or not a jpeg file,not judge by the suffix?

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia - [Magic number (programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29).

> JPEG image files begin with FF D8 and end with FF D9.

You just check that first and last byte of your stream match ones quoted.